# Include Blank Tag in XML

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Using the below SQL query  I am generating an XML File like below.

```
SELECT CAST((SELECT         
(
   SELECT                               
        ICase,
        DPCRef                          
   FROM 
      #HD HD WHERE HD.OrdRef=PICK.OrdRef
   GROUP BY        
        ICase,
        DPCRef 

   FOR XML PATH('HD'), TYPE
 ),
 (
    SELECT      
         PCode, 
         SOLnNt,
         (
                SELECT   SSCCRef 
                FROM    #SSCC LM
                WHERE   LD.OrdRef = LM.OrdRef AND LD.PCode=LM.PCode
                GROUP BY 
                  SSCCRef
                FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('SSCC'), TYPE
         ) 
    FROM    #LD LD
    WHERE   LD.OrdRef = PICK.OrdRef
    GROUP BY 
         PCode,   
         SOLnNt

    FOR XML PATH('LD'), TYPE
) 
FROM    #PICK PICK
GROUP BY OrdRef
    FOR XML PATH('PICK'), ROOT('PickOrder')) AS XML)  AS OrdersPickingConfirmationXML
```

Result:

```
<PICK>
    <HD>
      <CustCode>PAV001</CustCode>
      <OrdRef>813804</OrdRef>      
    </HD>
    <LD>
      <PCode>PROD0001</PCode>
      <Rotation>14/D004193</Rotation>      
      <SSCC>
        <SSCCRef>TEST 1</SSCCRef>
        <SSCCRef>TEST1</SSCCRef>
      </SSCC>
    </LD>
</PICK>
```

Sometime there will be no data in the #SSCC table.So that time that SSCC tag is not showing in XML.If there is no data I need to show it as `</SSCC>`. Is there anyway that I can get blank tag `</SSCC>`

Comment: Maybe wrap your subselect in an `ISNULL`?

Comment: I've formatted your sql and xml a bit and added single backticks around the tags, otherwise those are not rendered. Please review my changes so you can make those adjustments yourself next time.